# Can't Remove a node from a linked list searching by a variable

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that deletes a node from a linked list. Each node corresponds to a person, which contains information such as an ID which is different for everyone, and to find the node to remove I ask the user the ID of the person he wants to remove, but the code as it is right now is not removing anything and I can't figure out why. Here's the function:

```
int rmv (int counter){
int id = 0;
int i = 0;
int opt = -1;
user_t* ptr = (user_t*)malloc(sizeof(user_t));
ptr = start;
printf ("ID to remove: ");
scanf ("%d", &id);
while (ptr != NULL){
    if (ptr->id + 1 == id){
        ptr = ptr->prox->prox;
        printf ("Removed Successfully!\n");
    }
    else{
        ptr = ptr->prox;
    }
}
free (ptr);
while (opt < 0 || opt > 2){
    printf ("*********************************************************");
    printf ("\n-> 1-Go Back");
    printf ("\n-> 2-Exit");
    printf ("\n-> Option: ");
    scanf ("%d", &opt);
}
switch (opt){
    case 1: return (counter);
    break;
    case 2: exit (0);
}
```

}

Comment: `ptr = ptr->prox->prox;` That doesn't remove anything. It's just assigning to a local variable. Need to track the node before this, say `prev`, and then do something like: `pre->prox = ptr->prx`. Do a search - there are many examples of this.

Comment: `ptr = (user_t*)malloc(sizeof(user_t)); ptr = start;`. The `malloc` is totally unnecessary because the next line just overwrites the pointer and throws away the `malloc` value. It also results in a memory leak since the `malloc` value is lost and can never be freed.

Comment: You never modify any `ptr->prox` so you are never modifying the list. You'll also need special case handling for `start`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you completely @John3136. Why can't I do ptr->prox twice once I find the node befor the one I want to remove?

Comment: Thanks both of you who helped me, I was working on it for the past few hours and managed to correct the problem. Thanks for your advices!